# Argument of type Observable<Response> is not assignable to string type parameter / subscribe does not exist on type string

Tags: array, angular, typescript, observable, instagram-api

Buen día buenas tardes o buenas noches: Me dirijo a ustedes en busca de ayuda con un problema que estoy teniendo a la hora de usar la api de Visualizacion Basica de Instagram, manejo Angular en esta ocación, todos mis problemas surgen a partir de que no puedo hacer que renderize las imágenes, he seguido tutoriales y conozco que requests hacer, pero no consigo llegar a la segunda que necesito para traer las media_url de los posts.
Aquí les dejo mi código, voy a cambiar los datos personales por asteriscos por las dudas, aunque no se trate de una comunidad que se dedique a hacerle mal a las personas, solo por seguridad jeje.

instagram.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { InstagramComponent } from 'src/app/shop/home-6/instagram/instagram.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InstagramService {

  public urls :string[] = [];


  // Initialize 
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // Instagram Array
  public getInstagramData() {

    return this.http.get(`https://graph.instagram.com/*****************/media?access_token=************************************************************************************************************************************************&fields=id`);
  }

  public getMediaUrl(ids) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      const element = ids;
      this.urls.push(this.http.get(`https://graph.instagram.com/${element[i]}?access_token=************************************************************************************************************************************************&fields=media_url`));
    }
    return of(this.urls);
  }

}
```

instagram.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { InstagramService } from '../../../shared/services/instagram.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-instagram',
    templateUrl: './instagram.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./instagram.component.scss']
  })
export class InstagramComponent implements OnInit {
    public instagram;
    public ids:number[];
    public urls;
  
    constructor(private instaService: InstagramService) { }
  
    ngOnInit() {
      this.instaService.getInstagramData().subscribe(res => {
        this.instagram = res.json().data;
        console.log(this.instagram);
        
        // this.instagram.forEach(function(obj) {
        //   this.ids.push(obj.id);
        // });
        // console.log(this.ids);

        this.instaService.getMediaUrl(this.instagram).subscribe(res => {
          this.urls = res;
          console.log(this.urls);
        });

      });





    };
    public instaSlideConfig: any = {
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 7,
      slidesToScroll: 7,
      responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 1367,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 6,
              slidesToScroll: 6
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 5,
              slidesToScroll: 5,
              infinite: true
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 4,
              slidesToScroll: 4
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 3
            }
          }
        ]
      };
}
```

y me salen los siguientes errores:

ERROR in src/app/shared/services/instagram.service.ts(27,22): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

src/app/shop/home-6/instagram/instagram.component.ts(25,55): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

Por más vuelta que le doy, no logro que siga el rumbo hacia la funcion que trae las media_url y no se como más podría encararlo el problema.

Desde ya agradezco el tiempo que se tomen en leer esto.
Saludos y les deseo un feliz comienzo de año!

Comment: El primer error es por que estas tratando de pushear a un array de strings, un observable... primero trata de obtener esa data en json y luego trata de pushearlo.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay unas cuantas cosas que no se están asignando según el tipo de objetos que se están manejando.

El problema concreto de la pregunta aparece cuando asignas como dato de entrada un tipo incorrecto. Ejemplo de plantilla para mayor entendimiento:

```js
string[].push(Observable<T>);
```

Lógicamente, un objeto de tipo `string[]` "espera" que se inserten datos de tipo `string` en el formato de arreglo, no `Observable<T>` (`T` puede ser `any`, no es relevante para el ejemplo)

Es decir:

```js
public urls: string[] = [];

...() {
  this.urls.push(this.http.get('...'))
}
```

Lo que no es correcto. Pero hay varias maneras de solucionar esto.

Lo primero que tenemos que considerar, es el tipo de dato que es entendido de la respuesta de la consulta (Vamos a suponer que el endpoint retorna un texto simple)

Entonces, hacemos la consulta AJAX y luego rescatamos la información, ya sea utilizando una suscripción o una función callback de una conversión a Promise.

*Nota: Rxjs tiene muchas formas de suscribir a un Observable, así que tomaremos en consideración una de las más recomendadas por ser "más clara", pero esto es completamente opcional, puedes elegir la forma de suscripción que más te acomode, prefieras, requieras, o lo que sea*

*Nota 2: Es recomendable desuscribir los observables por temas de optimización. Ref: https://medium.com/swlh/rxjs-angular-unsubscribe-like-a-pro-ffeedec60aa7*

```js
this.http.get('...').subscribe({
  next: response => {
    this.urls.push(response as string);
  },
  error: handling => {
    console.error(handling);
  }
}).unsubscribe()
```

Sin embargo, debido a que lo que entiendo que necesitas es rescatar las urls, el método anterior no funcionaría como esperas, debido a que está desincronizado de la ejecución de la función.

Aquí es cuando entra en juego el uso de las funciones asíncronas. Vamos a tomar en consideración lo siguiente:

```js
// Tenemos la misma variable `urls` inicializada
public urls: string[] = [];

// Pero ahora vamos a usar una función asíncrona para que esta devuelva el objeto string[]
public async getUrls(ids: string[]): Promise<string[]> {
  for (const id of ids) {
    const responseText = await this.http.get(`https://.../${id}/...`).toPromise();
    this.urls.push(responseText as string);
  }
  return this.urls;
}
```

Entonces, puedes llamar esta función en tu componente:

```js
this.instaService.getUrls(this.instagram as string[]).then(urls => {
  this.urls = urls;
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```